# Image to InsertImage

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I've this code to insert an image to table in richtextbox.

```
            table.ForEachCell(delegate(TableCell cell, int rowIndex, int cellIndex)
        {
            if (rowIndex > 0)
            {
                if (dataTable.Rows[rowIndex - 1][columnsToDisplay[cellIndex]].GetType().ToString() != "System.Drawing.Bitmap")
                {
                    document.InsertText(cell.Range.Start, dataTable.Rows[rowIndex - 1][columnsToDisplay[cellIndex]].ToString());
                }
                else if (dataTable.Rows[rowIndex - 1][columnsToDisplay[cellIndex]].GetType().ToString() == "System.Drawing.Bitmap")
                {
                    var src = dataTable.Rows[rowIndex - 1][columnsToDisplay[cellIndex]];
                    Image img = new Image(src); // this line cause a problem
                    document.InsertImage(cell.Range.Start, img);
                }

            }
        });
```

Insert text is working fine but I want to insert an images which give an error:

> *Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'System.Drawing.Image'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image is an abstract base class, so it doesn't have a constructor.

Use this instead:

```
byte[] srcStream = (byte[])src;

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(srcStream);

Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: The src not came from file. It came from database table (byte[]). I tried Image img = Image.FromStream(src); . I got this error message: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.IO.Stream'.

Comment: You should cast your object to a byte[] and then create a stream from this array. See my edited answer

Comment: I've missed, my src is System.Drawing.Bitmap type. How can I cast this?

Comment: Just cast: `Image i = (Image)bitmapImg;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.drawing.image.aspx)

```
// Create image.
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(src);
```